# Zend Framework Bootstrap.php, Database Model, and Form

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, authentication, model

So I am working on a sample database project.
I have a LoginController.php, a Faculty database, and a login page (phtml).

I get the error Fatal error: Class 'Faculty_DB' not found in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/InternProject1/application/controllers/LoginController.php on line 25

In the LoginController.php I have the following (plus some more):

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $login = new Form_Login();
    //$this->view->login = $login; 

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if($request->isPost())
    {
        $data = $request->getPost();
        //$this->isValid(
        if($this->getRequest()->getPost())
        {
            $username = $request->getParam('username');
            $password = $request->getParam('password');
            // echo " What you entered is: $username and $password";
//line 24       
            $faculty = new Faculty_DB();
//then conditions for validation.
```

This references

```
class Faculty_DB extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
```

which is located in application/models/ directory

I have the following in Bootstrap.php

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoLoader->registerNamespace(array('App_'));
        $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace' => '',
            'resourceTypes'     =>
                array('form'=>
                    array('path'        => 'forms/',
                        'namespace'     => 'Form_'
                    ),
                ),
            ));
        return $autoLoader;         
    }
}
```

Any clue on how to fix this?
I tried the following:

```
 protected function _initResourceAutoloader()
 {
     $autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
         'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
         'namespace' => 'Application',
     ));

     $autoloader->addResourceType( 'model', 'models', 'Model');
     return $autoloader;
 }
```

but when I do that, it tells me it can't find my Login_Form;

Comment: try name your model class Model_Faculty_DB and rename file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your application namespace is `Application`, try:

- Put your faculty DB class in `application/models/Faculty.php`
- Name it `Application_Model_Faculty`
- Extend it from `Application_Model_DbTable_Faculty`
- Put the DbTable class in `application/models/DbTable/Faculty.php`

Since you are using `Zend_Application`, it will take care of setting up the autoloader and special prefixes like `Form_`, `Model_`, `Plugin_` etc for you, so you can safely remove the `_initAutoload` and `_initResourceAutoloader` from your Bootstrap.

Comment: ya, what Drew said. Use the the Zend Framework Defaults it will save you lots of head aches (until you have a compelling reason to change them. Because I don't like the way it looks. Is not compelling). Everything you are currently doing is overriding the preset defaults see http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html#zend.loader.autoloader-resource.module for  a good idea of the default namespaces.

Comment: The path for Faculty.php should be `application/models/DbTable/Faculty.php`, not `application/model/DbTable/Faculty.php`, but otherwise I agree :> +1

Comment: @WildWorxUK Thanks for noticing that, I updated the answer to use `models` as it should be, not `model` for the path.